# Failed to resolve entry for package "reactstrap" (React + Vite)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite

I followed the instruction in the reactsrap documentation but whenever i run "npm run dev", there is an error saying

`X [ERROR] Failed to resolve entry for package "reactstrap". The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json. [plugin vite:dep-scan]`

`src/App.tsx:4:24:4 │ import  { Button } from 'reactstrap';`

Here is the content of App.tsx

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import reactLogo from './assets/react.svg'
import viteLogo from '/vite.svg'
import  { Button } from 'reactstrap';
import './App.css'

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  return (
    <>
        <Button color="danger">Danger!</Button>;
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

ps. this is where i got the [reactstrap installation instruction](https://reactstrap.github.io/?path=/docs/home-installation--page)

I just want to use reactstrap with react + vite.

Comment: You have added reactstrap to your app's dependency through the package.json, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try install package again with:

```
npm install --save bootstrap
```

Then:

```
npm install reactstrap react react-dom
```